# WiFi never shuts off on Nexus 5 running Lollipop

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

I have Nexus 5 on Android Lollipop. When I check the battery graph, it always shows my WiFi radio as ON, even when I am using 3G and have specifically turned it off. I have observed that it only shuts off in airplane mode.

[image: Wi-fi was turned off during this whole time period]

<sub>Screenshot (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

How to correct this behavior?

Comment: I believe that this question is the same as your own:

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105908/even-with-wifi-turned-off-it-is-still-the-biggest-battery-drainer-s5-mini/105926#105926

Comment: @Megatron Actually Lollipop devices consume more battery than the Kitkat version does. And mostly lollipop users of nexus 5 complaining about Wifi radio problem. See the [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/battery-drain-t2939701) for a detailed review on this and [google forums post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79567) some fixes provided there you can try.

Answer (score -1):

I have a nexus 5 and had the same problem. I found an app called [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en) and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: It would  help more if you consider to add a link for the said app. Please do so.